# Can Groovy Be Used to Execute PigUnit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, apache-pig

Since Pig code is executed via a script, it would be symmetrical if Pig code could be tested via a script as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems so. If the tests can be written in Java, then can be written in Groovy. From the mailing list, seems like [some people already wrote Groovy](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-dev/201312.mbox/%3CJIRA.12685974.1387647821229.11295.1388048031205@arcas%3E) scripts tests.